# Replace the values in a column based on frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (3.7 million rows) with a column with different country names

```
   id  Country
   1   RUSSIA     
   2   USA     
   3   RUSSIA   
   4   RUSSIA   
   5   INDIA   
   6   USA   
   7   USA   
   8   ITALY   
   9   USA   
   10  RUSSIA
```

I want to replace INDIA and ITALY with "Miscellanous" because they occur less than 15% in the column

My alternate solution is to replace the names with there frequency using

```
df.column_name = df.column_name.map(df.column_name.value_counts())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Country')['id']
         .transform('size')
         .div(len(df))
         .lt(0.15), 
       'Country'] = 'Miscellanous'
```

Or

```
df.loc[df['Country'].map(df['Country'].value_counts(normalize=True)
                                      .lt(0.15)), 
       'Country'] = 'Miscellanous'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put all country whose frequency is less than a threshold into the "Misc" category:

```
threshold = 0.15
freq = df['Country'].value_counts(normalize=True)
mappings = freq.index.to_series().mask(freq < threshold, 'Misc').to_dict()

df['Country'].map(mappings)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dictionary` and `map` for this:

```
d = df.Country.value_counts(normalize=True).to_dict()
df.Country.map(lambda x : x  if d[x] > 0.15 else 'Miscellanous' )
```

**Output**:

```
id
1           RUSSIA
2              USA
3           RUSSIA
4           RUSSIA
5     Miscellanous
6              USA
7              USA
8     Miscellanous
9              USA
10          RUSSIA
Name: Country, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option

```
s = df.value_counts()
s = s/s.sum()
s = s.loc[s<.15].reset_index()
df = df.replace(s['Place'].tolist(),'Miscellanous')
```